Addpoly function adds 95%CIs in text despite specifying 90% using the level argument
I've created a forest plot with subgroups based on an rma.mv object in metafor. We are reporting 90% CI's which appear correctly next to each row of individual effect size estimates when using the forest function with the level argument.
res <- rma.mv(yi = g, 
              V = V, 
              random = ~ 1 | study / es_id,  
              data = df,
              method = "REML",
              test = "t")
forest(res,
       xlim = c(-16, 6.75),
       at = c(-4, -2, 0, 2, 4),
       alim = c(-4, 7.25),
       ylim = c(-2,18.5),
       ilab = cbind(df$measure, df$norm_delta_mean, df$norm_delta_sd, df$slow_delta_mean, df$slow_delta_sd), 
       ilab.xpos = c(-11, -8.75, -7.5, -5.75, -4.5),
       slab = df$descriptor, order = training_status,
       mlab = summary_labs_str("RE Model for All Studies", res),
       rows = c(2:6, 10:14), header = "Author(s) and Year",
       cex = 0.95,
       addpred = TRUE,
       level = 90)

The issue I'm encountering is that when using addpoly to add the overall summary effect with labels to the figure, using the level = 90 argument alters the polygon and associated PIs as expected (i.e., at the 90% level) but does not alter the text (i.e., Estimate + CIs) as these remain at the 95% level.
addpoly(res, row= 9, level = 90, mlab=summary_labs("Subgroup RE Model", res), addpred = TRUE, cex = 0.875, annotate = TRUE)

What am I missing?

It is not clear to me what text are you referring to. Here is a fully reproducible example that works fine:
library(metafor)
dat <- escalc(measure="RR", ai=tpos, bi=tneg, 
                            ci=cpos, di=cneg, 
              data=dat.bcg, slab=paste0(author, ", ", year))
res <- rma(yi, vi, data=dat)
forest(res, header=TRUE, ylim=-2, level=90)
addpoly(res, level=90)

Both the summary polygon drawn by forest() and the one drawn by addpoly() are both based on 90% CIs and the annotations on the right are correct.

Hi Wolfgang, thanks for the reply. It's the text of the summary effects for the overall model and then for each subgroup on the right side of the forest plot. The estimate is accurate, but the CI's presented are the 95% CI's rather than 90% (have triple checked this). All of the estimates and 90% CIs for the individual effects are accurate. See here (sorry external link, hopefully it works) where the red boxes are what I'm trying to describe: https://photos.app.goo.gl/RMRYW61jjFSUwhoa8

Can you provide a fully reproducible example?

Hi Wolfgang – sent you an email.
